# Combining mandatory and arbitrary optional constructor arguments with Groovy

Tags: groovy, jvm, kotlin

I am trying to determine, purely out of interest, whether it is possible to completely remove the need to use the Builder pattern in Groovy by using named and default constructor arguments; that is, to solve the telescoping constructor problem using only the built in language features.

For example, in Kotlin, it is possible to do the following:

```
data class Thing(val mandatory1: Int,
             val mandatory2: Int,
             val optional1: Int = 100,
             val optional2: Int = 200,
             val nullable: Int? = null)

   fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        val things = listOf(
                Thing(1, 2),
                Thing(1, 2, 3),
                Thing(1, 2, 3, 4),
                Thing(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                Thing(1, 2, optional2 = 4),
                Thing(1, 2, optional1 = 4),
                Thing(1, 2, nullable = 4),
                Thing(  nullable=400,
                mandatory1 = 800,
                optional1 = 300,
                optional2 = 700,
                mandatory2 = 600))

        things.forEach { t -> println(t) }
   }
```

This yields the following output:

```
Thing(mandatory1=1, mandatory2=2, optional1=100, optional2=200, nullable=null)
Thing(mandatory1=1, mandatory2=2, optional1=3, optional2=200, nullable=null)
Thing(mandatory1=1, mandatory2=2, optional1=3, optional2=4, nullable=null)
Thing(mandatory1=1, mandatory2=2, optional1=3, optional2=4, nullable=5)
Thing(mandatory1=1, mandatory2=2, optional1=100, optional2=4, nullable=null)
Thing(mandatory1=1, mandatory2=2, optional1=4, optional2=200, nullable=null)
Thing(mandatory1=1, mandatory2=2, optional1=100, optional2=200, nullable=4)
Thing(mandatory1=800, mandatory2=600, optional1=300, optional2=700, nullable=400)
```

The line of particular interest is where:

```
Thing(1, 2, optional2 = 4),
```

yields

```
Thing(mandatory1=1, mandatory2=2, optional1=100, optional2=4, nullable=null)
```

Note that I was able to set **optional2** without having had to set **optional1**.  I am not sure this is possible in Groovy but, then again, I am far from expert.

As a point of interest, looking at the generated byte code, the Kotlin compiler appears to generate a single constructor and then rewrites the instantiation statements to pass the optional arguments at the correct point in the argument list.

So, to the Groovy experts, is this simply not possible in Groovy or am I yet to find the correct syntax?

Thanks in advance,

Simon

Comment: One of my firends points me to some groovy feature named *named argument constructor*. It doesn't look like a complete counterpart of kotlin named paramters, but it may work in some situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in groovy. For example:

```
Class Thing{
    def x
    def y
    def z = 5
}
```

At this point you don't even need a constructor if all you plan to do is assign values. you can just say:

```
new Thing(x: "Hello", y:"World", z:6) //if you want to overwrite the defualt value of z.
```

If you read section 1.4 of this document: http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html, It states that you can choose between having positional constructors or named constructors.

My example is using a named argument constructor which gives more power to the one calling the constructor.

If you want any variables to be mandatory you will need to use a positional constructor, which is akin to how it's done in straight java.

if you define a constructor for your class, then you are using positional constructors and can not used named argument constructors any more for that class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is close to what I was after, and I must add is a great feature of groovy. The only problem is that all the properties are now optional.

Comment: Ahh I see. I didn't fully understand the question. Let me research and possibly revise my answer.

Comment: Thanks @switch201. I read that document and reached the same conclusion. I still think Groovy is great though; it's a very picky point that I have raised.